# Changing the width of a text field to show all charecters

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm developing a app where I have a rails code simply like this-

```
<input type="text" readonly="readonly" value="<%= linkbunch_url(@link.link) %>" />
```

Now the value here is more than 40 characters long. But the text field only showing 33 characters. So I added 'size' and 'maxlength' attribute but it didn't work. I also added CSS styling to the width:500px etc. But it didn't work. By the eay I'm using twitter bootstrap in rails. So is there any method in twitter bootstrap to format this field or any simple css or html to do this??

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

reference: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms

You may try to add a class of any of the following:

- input-xxlarge
- span12 (or any value that suitable to your parent container)

Answer (score 0):

It's weird that adding a width via CSS didn't work. There may be a bootstrap style that is overriding your set width.

Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/FBxHh/1/ didn't work?

```
<input type="text" class="myInput" readonly="readonly" value="lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum" />
```

css: `.myInput { width: 500px; }`